# How can I set up Web Filters, Time Restrictions and logging via user account login

Tags: logging, user-management

We have a small network (between 30-50 computers) and I have just recently installed a Windows server using Windows Server 2008 software. We have a unique setup where we are "piggybacking" off a business network. Our department runs our own server.

We have top level content filtering in place via St. Bernard and Sonicwall before the connection reaches the server.

The Sonicwall handles DHCP connections and access to the internet via MAC filtering.

Our server has access to the internet and we want to deploy it as the DHCP server for the department.

As management we want to be able to assign internet access to individual user accounts (not individual workstations) and have them on a time table as to when they can get access to the internet. 
I'm assuming that I may need to install third-party software (would be great if there were free solutions) and this software would also handle web activity logging for each individual user. What would be some suggestions for software and the procedure of getting something like this set up? This is the first time I am working with servers and so far have only set up individual user accounts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no access to the sonic wall...

some of my clients have got the ISA 2007 (some even upgraded to Forefront). 
Properly configured this will do what you need. although not sure if it needs a third party app to produce pretty web activity reports.

Or an open source alternative check out Squid + SARG (Squid Analysis Report Generator).

Both solutions would require all traffic to be routed through the server (ideally on separate NIC's) and both could be Active Directory users and IP/MAC ACL's.

You will have to completely separate your network from the "Business network".

If you want help or more info PM me.

hope this helps / puts you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time working with servers, you're biting off more than you can chew.

That said, most webfilters/proxies have this option (as do Sonicwalls, depending on the version), as do some routers and switches.  If you can't do it with your SonicWall for whatever reason, you're looking at buying another product, which sounds kind of like begging for a big headache to me.  Your best option to find another product is probably to do a Google search to get product recommendations for a webfilter that does support the options and features you want, and propose buying it.  Get a demo first, though, to make sure it's not going to be too horrible to administer, since that sounds like it'll fall on you.  (And for logging and granular access restrictions to internet access, you'll need a webfilter or proxy.)